# Setting flags for users (Active Directory)

Tags: c#, active-directory

at the moment I am trying to write some code to help our support and having some problems. I am creating a user in the OU, setting all needed attributes and having trouble setting the flags.

```
string ADPath1 = "LDAP://127.0.0.1/OU=TEST,DC=abc,DC=def,DC=local";
string ADUser = "admin";
string ADPassword = "somepw";
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ADPath1, ADUser, ADPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

I am connecting, and setting everything up

```
DirectoryEntries users = de.Children;
DirectoryEntry newuser = users.Add("CN=" + "Artemij Voskobojnikov", "user");
newuser.Properties["property"].Add("XXX");
```

Now I'd like to setup the userAccountControl-propery and am trying to do the following:

```
const int UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = 0x0040;
const int UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 0x10000;
int user_flags = UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE + UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD;

newuser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = user_flags
```

I am getting an error, something like "Server cannot execute the operation". Is there any way to do this or do I have to use UserPrincipal?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context and bind to the OU=Test container
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN", "OU=TEST"))
{
    // create a new user
    UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

    // set first name, last name, display name, SAM Account Name and other properties easily
    user.DisplayName = "Artemij Voskobojnikov";
    user.GivenName = "Artemij";
    user.Surname = "Voskobojnikov";
    user.SamAccountName = "AVoskobojnikov";

    // set some flags as appropriate for your use
    user.UserCannotChangePassword = true;
    user.PasswordNeverExpires = true;

    // save user
    user.Save();
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I was already working with the Principals and was thinking about a second possibility but I guess I should just choose the easier approach.